# Wix.com - is it possible to reference Contacts (or Members) from a Collection?

Tags: velo

I'm new to Wix.com so apologies in advance for the trivial question.

I'd like to be able to reference site members from records in a Collection in Wix.com.  I have some additional information that relates to a subset of members.

In Content Manager I can create a new Collection fine, but the only collections listed in the "Referenced Collection" dropdown when I try to create a field of type Reference or Multi-Reference are my own collections, not the system ones (I'm assuming members/contacts are a sort of built-in collection.)

So if I can't do this, is there a reasonable workaround?

I can add custom fields to members and selectively make this available by role, but it's still restrictive as only a limited number of field types are available here and there's no way to model one-many or many-many relationships.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so my question above was trivial.

It *is* possible to create references to collections such as members. The key step is to make these system collections visible. In Content Manager>Manage Collections, use the "Advanced Settings" option and toggle the "Wix App Collections".

Once done, this makes numerous collections visible in addition to the custom ones created for the site.

See "How to show or hide Wix App Collections" in the Wix help centre at https://support.wix.com/en/article/content-manager-working-with-wix-app-collections